# Why does Harry Potter wear glasses?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, spells

Is there some in-Universe (or somewhat canonical) explanation for why Harry wears glasses - either 100% of the time, or at least, when playing Quiddich?

Surely, given assorted spells, there should be one to repair either the issues with his near-sightedness, or, more likely, to act as lenses (being how magic is used to replace ANY technology, it ought to be able to replace lense-making).

P.S. I seem to recall a spell to make someone see better from afar, but not sure of the details.

Comment: One of the great HP debates that I had never heard of until now... Sigh.

Comment: The spell you're remembering is probably one that improved his glasses(but not his eyesight) during the match with the heavy rain.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - was that sarcastic?

Comment: @apoorv020 - No, it was most certainly not that one. Don't remember any details, but it was specifically related to eyesight and not fixing (AFAIK de-fogging) glasses - and I don't think it was even HP who was the beneficiary.

Comment: it's a writing ploy that Rowling used to make give him a weakness, since he's the boy wonder and all.  :-D

Comment: Just like most people, Harry does not wear his glasses while asleep (he is mentioned to put on his glasses when he wakes up multiple times in the books).  This makes it much less than 100%.  Incidentally, was he wearing his glasses during the second Triwizard task?

Comment: @DVK A genetic pre-disposition to bad eye sight such as one not caused by a traumatic incident tends to occur around puberty because that is when the eye undergoes the most change and thus the most can go wrong in the eyes development. I am a M.D. In ophthalmology so I do believe I know what I am talking about.

Comment: Secretly...Harry was a huge fan of Geordi Laforge.

Comment: Because he can’t fight the Dark Lord if he can’t *see* the Dark Lord? :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Poor eyesight simply appears to be a non-reversible ailment among wizards.

We have ample evidence that this is so, by the 19 other mentioned wizard and witches who also wear them.

Amelia Bones (monocle), Borgin (pince-nez), Aberforth Dumbledore, Mafalda Hopkirk

Albus Dumbledore (half-moon)

> ‘Exactly,’ said Dumbledore, looking very seriously over the top of his
>   half-moon glasses.

Minerva McGonagall (square)

> Instead he was
>   smiling at a rather severe-looking woman who was wearing square
>   glasses exactly the shape of the markings the cat had had around
>   its eyes.

Myrtle Warren (thick lenses), Bob Ogden (thick lenses), Harry Potter (round)

James Potter (round)

> The tall, thin, black-haired man standing next to her put his
>   arm around her. He wore glasses, and his hair was very untidy. It
>   stuck up at the back, just like Harry’s did.

Rufus Scrimgeour (wire-rimmed), Rita Skeeter (rhinestone), Tofty (pince-nez)

Sybill Trelawney (thick lenses), Arthur Weasley (horn-rimmed)

Percy Weasley (horn-rimmed)

> ‘I – don’t – want –’ said Percy thickly, as the twins forced the
>   jumper over his head, knocking his glasses askew.

Wilhelmina Grubbly-Plank (monocle), Eldred Worple

[wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Glasses)

As to Harry's particular case, as Syltherincess states he appears to simply be genetically predisposed to poor eyesight like his father.

With the large base of people wearing glasses in world it leads to a pretty solid assumption that it cant be fixed magically. Not really a plot hole when you look at the vast list of individuals, simply something Rowling planed magic to have no answer to.

Comment: Given that poor (muggle) eyesight can be fixed with a simple, but rather expensive operation, might that also not apply to wizards? Perhaps poor eyesight is fixable but there are reasons why such a thing is to be avoided (cultural / financial).

Comment: @Valorum some of these listed are some of the most powerful wizards of their time, seems "if" a cure existed they would be most likely to have gotten it. Magically a spell would be "free" only if it required some form of advanced potion with special ingredients could we argue cost was a factor.

Comment: [This man](http://assets.rollingstone.com/assets/images/story/20130718-bill-gates-624x420-1374261123.jpg) can literally afford anything. For some reason, he hasn't had laser-eye surgery to correct his eyesight.

Comment: @Valorum dont forget lasik is a relatively new tech, and has full % chances of issues, it also can only improve eye sight to a certain degree in which many recipients still need glasses, and is only usable on certain types of eye issues anyway. its a quick fix for mild vision loss, Harrys is relatively bad. http://www.aao.org/eye-health/treatments/lasik

Comment: multi focus lasik isnt even legal in the US yet, http://www.allaboutvision.com/visionsurgery/presby-lasik.htm

Comment: I am reasonably sure that Bill Gates can afford to fly to Canada or wherever the treatment is legal.

Comment: @Valorum risking your multi billion dollar eyes for a minor procedure that can and does go horribly wrong for minor eyesight correction =/ magic that works or doesnt

Comment: Spells can go bad as well :-)

Comment: @Valorum I think the issue is not that you couldn't use a wand to make the kinds of reshaping that are made in lasik surgery, but that knowing what to do to the eye requires a modern medical understanding of how the eye works, what it does, how it does it and so on and so forth, which wizards presumably wouldn't have, having basically eschewed science, having little need of it with their magic (plus the fact that magic breaks a lot of science). Magical medicine seems to rely more on finding spells and potions to do x or y by magic, rather than understanding anatomy and setting to work on it

Answer (score 51):

Harry wears his glasses during Quidditch because he cannot see without them. Why he cannot see without glasses, I think, has to be one of three reasons.

- Harry's poor eyesight is collateral damage from Avada Kedavra, the darkest of evil curses. Body parts that are damaged, destroyed, or severed due to dark curses don't seem to be repairable in Potterverse:

  > Mrs Weasley looked round and said, ‘I can’t make it grow back, not when it’s been removed by Dark Magic. But it could have been so much worse ... he’s alive.’
  >
  > *Deathly Hallows* - Page 66 - UK Hardcover
- Harry's eyesight is poor because the author wanted her hero to wear glasses.

  > When a fan asked J.K. Rowling why Harry Potter wears glasses, Rowling answered: "*Because I had glasses all though my childhood and I was sick and tired of the person in the books who wore the glasses was always the brainy one and it really irritated me and I wanted to read about a hero wearing glasses. It also has a symbolic function, Harry is the eyes onto the books in the sense that is always Harry's point of view, so there was also that, you know, facet of him wearing glasses*".
  >   JK Rowling - [BBC INTERVIEW 07.18.05](http://news.bbc.co.uk/cbbcnews/hi/newsid_4690000/newsid_4690800/4690885.stm)
- Harry inherited his poor eyesight from his father James Potter, and values other qualities in himself (much like the reason Snape doesn't attend to his hygiene, per JKR) and doesn't feel that he needs to "fix" his eyesight.

Regarding spells, Hermione uses Impervius to protect Harry's glasses during Quidditch in *PoA*. There is a spell called Obscuro, which blindfolds a person (Hermione uses it on Phineas Nigellus). the Supersensory Spell lets a person see objects that are out of their line of vision (Ron uses this to pass his Muggle driving test). The Conjunctivitis Curse affects the vision of anyone hit with it (Sirius suggested it to Harry as a possible Curse for the first task of the Tri-Wizard Tournament; Madame Maxime uses it against the giants when they acted up when she and Hagrid went to meet with them). As an aside, Oculus Reparo does not appear in the books; it's a movie-only spell.

**ETA:** Just adding confirmation that James Potter did indeed wear glasses:  *This was in contrast to the only wizarding photograph on the walls, which was a picture of four Hogwarts students standing arm in arm, laughing at the camera. With a leap of pleasure, Harry recognised his father; his untidy, black hair stuck up at the back like Harry’s and he, too, wore glasses*. (*Deathly Hallows* - Kreacher's Tale)

Comment: "... assuming one believes the poor eyesight is collateral damage from Avada Kedavra" - that's the part that is bothering me about the whole setup. It doesn't seem to be ever implied

Comment: @DVK - I reworded my answer. I don't think that it's implied directly in the books that Harry's eyesight is poor because of the Avada Kedavra curse. That said, I think it's one of three possibilities, which I have clarified in my edit. I'm leaning towards #2 myself. :)

Comment: Does #2 imply JKR was not brainy?

Comment: Whoa! #3 just killed #1!!! If James had poor eyesight, you do NOT need Avada to explain lack of healing - James didn't have the excuse of Dark-Magic caused poor eyesight! Did he wear glasses in school?

Comment: BTW, this STILL doesn't seem to give me a fully satisfactory answer. I mean, #2 shows Word Of God, but to me it then looks like a sloppy plot hole - no provided reason why it couldn't be fixable, yet not fixable because Mary Sue hero must wear glasses.

Comment: @DVK - I am completely unsuprised that you are not satisfied! Okay, re: James Potter wearing glasses at Hogwarts, I can't find any *canon* evidence that he did. James is quite thoroughly described in chapter 28 of *OOTP* and no mention of glasses is made. James was 20 when Harry was born and he *is* wearing glasses in the Mirror of Erised. I still don't think that's proof that James wore glasses at Hogwarts; many people don't have vision problems until they are past 20. How genetic is poor eyesight? Albus-Severus Potter is described as looking exactly like Harry, sans the glasses. :)

Comment: @DVK The Mirror of Erised showed mostly what the onlooker desired to see, didn't it? Harry wished to see his father and imagined that they did have a lot in common. So, if there's no other canonical proof, the Adava Kedavra theory (see also my answer) might still stand.

Comment: How genetic is poor eyesight? - is pretty heritable IIRC

Comment: @OpaCitiZen - Hm. Good point

Comment: @OpaCitiZen -- From *DH*: *This was in contrast to the
only wizarding photograph on the walls, which was a picture of four Hogwarts students standing arm in arm, laughing at the camera. With a leap of pleasure, Harry recognised his father; his untidy, black hair stuck up at the back like Harry’s and he, too, wore glasses*. It's in the chapter *Kreacher's Tale*

Comment: @Slytherincess Great find, thanks! This seriously lessens the likeliness of the Adava Kedavra theory indeed - yet even this does not rule it out completely.

Comment: @OpaCitiZen -- I agree! It doesn't rule out the possibility of collateral damage from the Avada Kedavra curse. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess, IIRC, wasn't there a picture of baby harry riding around on a children's broom, before the Avada Kedavra curse, with his glasses on?

Comment: @John -- That was in *Deathly Hallows*, yes, but I don't know if Harry was wearing glasses as a baby. I'll check. Okay, no, no mention of glasses: *A black-haired baby was zooming in and out of the picture on a tiny broom, roaring with laughter, and a pair of legs that must have belonged to James were chasing after him.* :)

Comment: @Slytherincess, ok, I think I may have just pictured the glasses on him in my mind, or maybe it was in the movie :) thanks!

Comment: @Slytherincess - Just to counter the third reason (inherited from his father): *Harry got his mother's eyes* :)

Comment: @hims056 -- I get what you're saying, but the body is very complex. I myself got my mother's eyes -- exactly, down to one of our lids squinting up a bit more than the other when we smile -- yet I need glasses and my mother doesn't. I don't think "Harry has Lily's eyes" has the same meaning as cloning.

Answer (score 28):

There's a difference between healing an injury, i.e. returning someone to their natural state, and attempting to override one's natural physical characteristics.

There are several healing spells mentioned in the books, such as repairing a broken nose, removing/regrowing bones and healing cuts. These are not trivial spells and they can go disastrously wrong if cast improperly. Even these spells only speed up the body's natural healing process; some injuries are so traumatic that they can't even be healed by magic.

IIRC the only magic powerful enough to physically alter someone's appearance (and eyesight) is polyjuice potion, and that wears off fairly quickly.

Plus, I can't help feeling it would be considered a fairly gross thing to do, to use magic on your own body... kind of like plastic surgery when used for vanity's sake. It feels like more of a dark wizard thing... like splitting one's soul.

Comment: Yes, splitting one's soul, mildly altering the shape of the eye's lens.  Totally the same. ;-)

Comment: If you don't believe this, see book 2.

Comment: @Jeff: I know, right?! And it's not even *mildly* altering the shape of the lens because Harry's eyesight was **really bad**! Maybe he could get immortal sight or... hey, are you being sarcastic? ;)

Comment: @Kyralessa: Sorry. I was referring to the healing spells gone wrong. If you don't believe it, see book 2.

Comment: You are clearly evil if you use magic to become more attractive. Like shrinking a pair of beavery front-teeth for example. ;>

Comment: @Aifos Alright, look, I wish I hadn't made any references to dark magic, it's just the overall impression I got. I'm not trying to say it's evil just... you know... icky. Don't forget, Hermione was embarrassed when her DIY dental work was noticed.

Comment: Although Hermione lets the school healer shrink her teeth to less than their natural size after the polyjuice cat thing goes wrong.

Comment: @radiotable It was actually after a Densaugeo hex incident with Draco Malfoy cronies, not after the polyjuice going wrong! It happened in GoF.

Answer (score 11):

Eyesight may not be viewed as a deformity by the magical world.

Speaking for someone who's worn glasses since they were in primary school, I'm not sure they'll want corrective surgery if and when such surgery that would correct all their vision faults becomes available.  Viewing the world through glasses and viewing the world without glasses will mean a huge shift in perspective and having to relearn all sorts of things.

Maybe the spell **is** available, but not everyone makes use of it.  Harry couldn't when he was younger (imagine the Dursley's response) and may just not care one way or another at current time.

Percy Weasley, Dumbledore and Prof. McGonagall too wear glasses.

McGonagall and Dumbledore may like the way they look with glasses. (Being able to look over the tops of your glasses at students when you need to intimidate is widely regarded as a good thing by some teachers.)

Comment: see my response to apoorv020. Based on both the source text (Harry having trouble during Quidditch), and my own experience playing sports with glasses, indicate that Harry would have made use of the spell if he could. It's about simple physical sports-related problem, not about psychological angles. I fail to see either of the 3 other glass wearers playing high-impact sports :)))) - and I agree that they may like the glasses "professorial" look.

Answer (score 10):

Well, we know that his vision wasn't perfect, and so he needed them in the Muggle world. It seems like wizards don't use any modern muggle technology, and contact lenses would definitely fit into that (Plus how could he afford them, he didn't exactly have muggle money...)

One not as well known thing about Lasik surgery is that people should be 18 to do it. Why, might you ask? Well, it's because eyes are still changing significantly until one reaches about that age. So, even if he did want to ditch the glasses, he wouldn't be old enough for Lasik. I'm going to assume that the same thing would be true of any wizard treatment that might exist.

Also, in order to fix vision, one has to know a fair amount of optics and human biology. Things have to be done exactly correctly, or else one will mess things up even further. With some of the other things we see fixed, it's more of a matter of getting things to an appropriate size, and approximately the right location, but for eyes, they must be very precise, to the micron level.

Finally, the glasses to a large degree represent many things which Harry often represented, intelligence, respect, little money (Especially with the broken glasses to begin with), and not particularly physically strong.

Comment: If a wizard can figure out how to manipulate memories, I think reshaping an eyeball would be child's play.

Comment: @Ryan: Manipulating, yes. Manipulating in a way to fix it, well, not quite as easy. Besides, pretty much all of the memory manipulation we see is destructive, which is a bit easier.

Comment: All of this has got me thinking, it'd be a simple spell to make it so someone couldn't see. Wonder why it's never attempted...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto Good call on the blindness spell. But I would still think that someone would have figured out eye repair. They'd be sitting on a gold mine Trebek!

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - sorry, but I'm not buying the "optics/biology" hurdle. They don't seem to have any problem healing any other parts of the body, even without major biological knowledge. As far as the last paragraph, it is undeniably 100% true, but I was sincerely hoping for some (at least ret-conned) in-universe info. JKR interview or something

Comment: @DVK: healing other injuries is merely restoring their bodies to their natural state.  I'm sure they could heal you if your eye was cut (but not removed!  See Mad-Eye), but in this case the 'natural state' is a misshapen lens.

Comment: @DVK: *Healing* usually involves speeding up biological processes that would have occurred anyhow. A broken bone will mend, if set properly, but magic could make it heal very quickly. Vision does not heal itself, so there's no process for magic to speed up.

Comment: Actually some of the wizzards do use modern technology, if you mean glasses.  Multiple professors wear glasses through out the films/books.  Also we rocket powered motorcycles, flying cars, etc.

Comment: @Chadddada: Glasses aren't all that modern really... They've been around for 300 years or so, at least.

Comment: Reading glasses have been around since at least the 14th century.

Comment: > "destructive, which is a bit easier"... I believe, laser surgery in at least some cases is about evaporating the "extra" eye tissue to the remainder of the dome is curved differently - making a better lens. Sounds destructive to me :) Just gotta have micrometer precision with where the magic hits...
(Reminds me of Star Wars discussions about why there's place for Force-throwing bodies around and Force-choke, but not a subtle Force-pinch of a nerve, artery, stopping of lungs or the heart... Force-crushing of droids but not Force-tearing apart someone or something...)

Answer (score 9):

It could be a combination of several reasons:

- He really doesn't mind his glasses. After some time, glasses start feeling like a part of you. Plus, AFAIR, he isn't teased about his glasses in the wizarding world. (I suspect that glasses are not considered uncool. Plus, Dumbledore and Lupin both wear glasses).
- He doesn't realize that magic can be used to cure everyday maladies (like tooth, pimples) etc. He views the hospital as something you go when you have misplaced every bone in your body or maybe poisoned yourself.
- They may not even have the good <s>technology</s> magic for it. Certainly they can do some wonderful stuff, but it may not be very safe, convenient or inexpensive. If there's an instantaneous cure for bad sight, I will take it. But if I have to wait three weeks in the hospital for it, nah.

Comment: I wear glasses. I can certainly say that the first bullet point is, if not 100% false, at least not true for 100% people. Heck, they play havoc with soccer. Never mind Quidditch.

Comment: @DVK:Yeah I had forgotten the violent sport factor of it.

Comment: I wouldn't give up my glasses, just like I wouldn't shave of my hair even if it gets in the way sometimes. I look much better with them.

Answer (score 8):

I have no idea whether there's a canonical answer to that, but if I had to draw up a theory I'd say his sight was damaged by the same spell that gave him that famous and apparently also **incurable** scar.

(On a side-note worthy of Captain Obvious I'd say having problems with his vision is quite symbolic: He's constantly looking back into memories or looking forward to his impending confrontation with his nemesis: focusing on the present is a kind of a struggle for him in itself.)

Comment: Moreover, Avada Kedavra was described as a _blinding_ jet of green light: "Sometimes, when he strained his memory during long hours in his cupboard, he came up with a strange vision: a blinding flash of green light and a burning pain on his forehead." (Book 1, chapter 2)

Comment: Slytherincess's answer just demolished the Avada Kedavra theory of poor eyesight (though she mentioned it herself) - James Potter wore glasses as well and he didn't have the same excuse as Harry.

Comment: @DVK I don't see why there HAS to be a connection between Harry and James wearing glasses. It is not uncommon to inherit bad vision from the parents but Harry might could just as well have bad eyesight for his own reasons. It is not clear just how bad his eyesight is but I think it is worth mentioning that he had glasses early. I'm no expert but people who get the same eye problems as their parents usually develop it later, around puberty. I would say that the idea that the green light damaged his eyes is still likely.

Comment: @Aifos - I'm strongly skeptical about "people who get the same eye problems as their parents usually develop it later". Do you have any references?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't. It is just something that my optician used to tell me. As I said, I'm no expert.

Comment: @DVK There’s no evidence that just because both James and Harry wore glasses they had the same eye problems. James might have had astigmatism while Harry is just myopic, for example.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - there's no certainty, but the likelyhood is there

Answer (score 2):

We know that technology in the magical world follows Muggle technology with a long delay.  Wizards use candles for lighting, fireplaces for heating, and a steam locomotive for traveling.

Both contact lenses and laser eye surgery are new technology, have improved a great deal in the last decade, and are still improving.  I would thus expect that contact lenses or laser eye surgery were not yet readily available in the wizarding world at the time the story of Harry Potter happened (eg. in 1997).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any canon for this, just my opinion. Harry wore glasses because it was the only physical way to tie him to James (other than his unruly hair which a lot of people have). Everyone commented on his eyes - his mother's eyes, but the glasses were the only thing that *visually* tie him to his father and made them look alike. If there were no glasses he would have been any ordinary boy with dark hair.

Remember when Hagrid first saw Dudley in the ocean shack? He was under the impression that Dudley was Harry until Harry stepped out and Hagrid saw the (James') glasses.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps he could have had his eyes fixed but it is a complex spell which needs a specialist in eye healing/surgery magic and they are hard to get appointments or Harry had not found out about the specialist yet.  Or perhaps one must be a certain age before the repair can be made by magic so that the eye continues to grow with the individual.  Plus, it may be very expensive/dangerous.