# Why doesn't Harry Potter use magic to fix his eyesight?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Harry Potter wear glasses?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/why-does-harry-potter-wear-glasses)

Something that always confused me reading the books and watching the films was the fact that Harry Potter is always breaking his glasses and repairing them. They have spells and medicine that can grow bones, remove memories and transform you into other people but fixing his eyes so he no longer needs glasses is beyond them?

Is there a reason he never gets his eyesight fixed?

Comment: Maybe he likes wearing glasses. I do. :)

Comment: A sci-fi fan might argue, that his eyesight was fixed by science (i.e. his glasses). Why use boring magic, if you can have awesomeness? ;) --- also, [nerd cred](http://brownsharpie.courtneygibbons.org/?p=1114), of course.

Comment: Good question, but it's already been asked: [Why does Harry Potter wear glasses?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/why-does-harry-potter-wear-glasses)

Comment: @Kevin There are some good answers on there that have cleared things up. Thanks.