# Would it have made any difference if Harry Potter didn't wear glasses?

Tags: harry-potter, parallel-universe, alternate-history

From [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3722/70767) interesting question and with its even more interesting answers, I deduce following:

1. Poor eyesight cannot be healed by even Magic
2. Harry had already been in trouble numerous times due to his poor
   eyesight.

**Update:** From comments, here are few incidents of movie/book:

1. In PoA, the Whomping Willow broke Harry's glasses
2. When Harry uses Floo Powder in CoS, his glass breaks.
3. Hermione places a charm on Harry's glasses in PoA to repel the rain during Quidditch.
4. Snape threw Harry so hard onto the dungeon floor that his glasses fell off out of the tent...

There are many more instances also (not able to recall).

So my question goes here: **keeping the diverse literature of Harry Potter in context, would there any major or minor impacts in plot, or story altogether if Harry didn't wear glasses?**

Comment: He would've bumped into things more?

Comment: I don't think so. Glasses are just an accessory and for most wizards an elegant clothing companion. I really don't think that wizards cannot heal poor eyesight due to defects in eyes or age but they rather don't mind to; they just keep wearing glasses, as most Muggles prefer them over eye lenses.

Comment: @TheDarkLord _sniff sniff_

Comment: This seems like it would generate very speculative answers. However, maybe if you included some examples of when he got into trouble due to poor eyesight, then it might be possible for answers to suggest how he situation may have been different if he had better vision.

Comment: @Longshanks I agree-but I knowingly did not include examples to avoid SPOILERS.

Comment: @KaranDesai Edit with [spoiler](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) tag.

Comment: Ohh okay-I did not know that-sorry I am new..Just give me two minutes-I'll edit the question

Answer (score 5):

Yes, arguably.

In Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, his glasses give the game away that he's Harry Potter in disguise.

> ‘I thought you wore glasses, Potter?’ breathed Greyback. ‘I found glasses!’ yelped one of the Snatchers skulking in the background. ‘There was glasses in the tent, Greyback, wait –’ And seconds later Harry’s glasses had been rammed back on to his face. The Snatchers were closing in, now, peering at him. ‘It is!’ rasped Greyback. ‘We’ve caught Potter!’

Later in the same book, his glasses give him some measure of protection from the smoke caused by the fiendfyre (allowing him to locate and rescue his school chums). Since he escaped at the last moment, you could argue that his glasses were instrumental in finding them.

> It’s – too – dangerous –!’ Ron yelled, but Harry wheeled in the air. His glasses giving his eyes some small protection from the smoke, he raked the firestorm below, seeking a sign of life, a limb or a face that was not yet charred like wood … And he saw them: Malfoy with his arms around the unconscious Goyle, the pair of them perched on a fragile tower of charred desks, and Harry dived.

Comment: Yeah-How could I forget that! :)

Comment: @KaranDesai - Rowling has written almost a million words of text about Harry Potter. It's not easy to remembe all of it.