# Is Harry Potter the only student with glasses?

Tags: harry-potter, meme

I recently got this meme:

[image: Panel 1: Close up on Harry's face, text at the bottom: "Look at me". Panel 2: View over Harry's shoulder as he looks at Snape on the ground holding his bloody neck. Text at the bottom: How are you the only student with glasses in the entire fuckin' film series?]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Since, I keep wondering if Harry Potter is really the only wizard student with glasses or if there are others? Specially since, according to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/132435/120088) answer, wizards cannot fix bad eyesight. I've started to watch some clips on YouTube to try find students with glasses and looked at pictures of the start-of-term feast but have so far not been able to identify another student with glasses.

Sources from the book or the films are accepted.

Comment: Presumably McGonagall did when she was at school, because we know (from Pottermore) that she became an animagus as a student and her cat form has spectacle markings. And Moaning Myrtle did too. Not the most recent though — I'll keep thinking.

Comment: The answer you quote already lists out every character who wears glasses (books and movies). Doesn't that kind of answer this question?

Comment: We know of several other students that wore glasses (James Potter, Moaning Myrtle), then there's adults who wear glasses but may or may not have done at school. However, I can't think of any named students who wore glasses while Harry was at school.

Comment: @shreedhar yes, it does indeed... didn't even think about this... thx!

Comment: Percy Weasley! Although he doesn't in the films. It isn't impossible that some of the Muggle-born students wear contact lenses (witches and wizards might as well, but we never see a wizard opticians so I don't know, but somebody must fit the glasses). Perhaps not though — they'd be much more practical for Quidditch but nobody ever suggests Harry tries them.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Percy did (not in the movies though), the books say he wore horn-rimmed glasses

Comment: I've found circumstantial evidence that there are wizarding opticians — in PoA Ron makes a joke about Harry needing to have his inner eye tested. That's the sort of joke you'd have to be familiar with the concept to make.

Comment: I think that the real answer here is that Snape only ever paid any attention to Harry, not that there weren't other students with glasses.

Comment: I don't think the TV show writers or even the book author herself gave it much thought. Except for Potter himself, whose glasses are part of his character, I'm pretty sure the other actors just arrived with what they have - those wearing glasses naturally were filmed with glasses, those who don't naturally have glasses didn't have in the film as well. So it's a question about ratio of actors wearing glasses in general.

Comment: Does Luna count? She wears specs on the train.

Comment: Spectacles are prone to reflection and refraction of images - in a filming setting that could potentially reveal unwanted details "behind the curtain" (e.g. the cameraman) that would either require the shoot to be redone, or require touch-up work after the fact.

Comment: Moaning Myrtle is famous.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

**Students with glasses:**

- Percy Weasley

> “I — don’t — want —” said Percy thickly, as the twins forced the
> sweater over his head, knocking his glasses askew.

- Myrtle

> I’d hidden because Olive Hornby was teasing me about my glasses.

- James Potter

> Harry recognized his father, his untidy black hair stuck up at the
> back like Harry’s, and he too wore glasses.

**Other wizards with glasses:**

- Arthur Weasley

> Mr. Weasley was slumped in a kitchen chair with his glasses off and
> his eyes closed.

- Albus Dumbledore

> “Exactly,” said Dumbledore, looking very seriously over the top of his
> half-moon glasses.

- Minerva McGonagall

> He turned to smile at the tabby, but it had gone. Instead he was
> smiling at a rather severe-looking woman who was wearing square
> glasses exactly the shape of the markings the cat had had around its
> eyes.

- Rita Skeeter

> Unemployment did not suit Rita.... there were a couple of false jewels
> missing from her winged glasses

- Sybill Trelawney

> Professor Trelawney moved into the firelight, and they saw that she
> was very thin; her large glasses magnified her eyes to several times
> their natural size

- Ernie Prang

> Ernie Prang, an elderly wizard wearing very thick glasses, nodded to
> Harry

- Rufus Scrimgeour

> “Well, it is clear to me that he has done a very good job on you,”
> said Scrimgeour, his eyes cold and hard behind his wire-rimmed glasses

- Aberforth Dumbledore

> The firelight made the grimy lenses of Aberforth’s glasses momentarily
> opaque

- Mafalda Hopkirk

> As she removed Mafalda’s spectacles and put them on, Harry checked
> his watch.

Comment: Although each of these characters might once have been a student, do you have any evidence that they wore glasses _while they were students_? It's much more common to need glasses as an adult than as a child, so most adults with glasses were never a child with glasses.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm pretty sure that the scene with James Potter is during his fifth year in Hogwarts. It's probably the Snape's Worst Memory chapter from OotP. Myrtle, of course, died before graduating. Most of Percy's scenes are pre-graduation.

Comment: @J.Mini Those may be, but "an elderly wizard wearing very thick glasses" who probably once went to Hogwarts, at which point he may well have had 20:20 vision, is a pretty big stretch for "student with glasses".

Comment: @IMSoP Hence the headline "Other wizards with glasses". To be fair, that's easy to overlook though. I've submitted some formatting to fix that.

Comment: @EgorHans, you can move McGonagall up too I think — she became an Animagus when she was at school, and the cat's fur includes the pattern of her glasses.

Comment: -1 As the question is about the "entire f***ing film series" and these quotes seem to mistake the books of the same name with the film series in question.

Comment: @DavidMulder The question says «Sources from the book or the films are accepted.».

Answer (score 73):

**Focusing purely on the films, there are a considerable number of <s>background extras</s> other pupils attending Hogwarts with Harry who wear glasses**

---

### Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone

**Prefect helping First Years to de-train**
[image]

**First Year in Great Hall**
[image]

**Random Hufflepuff in Great Hall**
[image]

**Different random Hufflepuff in Great Hall**
[image]

**Random Ravenclaw at flying lesson.**
[image]

**Random Gryffindor *and* Random Slytherin crossing quad.**
[image]

**Random Ravenclaw girl crossing quad.**
[image]

### Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets

**Ravenclaw girl in transfiguration class**
[image]

**Gryffindor boy in hallway**
[image]

**Gryffindor girl at duel**
[image]

**Gryffindor girl at duel**
[image]

### Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban

**Gryffindor girl in DADA class.**
[image]

### Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire

**Random boys at Yule Ball**
[image]

### Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince

**Luna Lovegood periodically wears Spectrespecs**
[image]

### Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part II

**Two Gryffindor boys in Great Hall**
[image]

**Ravenclaw girl in Great Hall**
[image]

**Ravenclaw boy in hallway**
[image]

Comment: "Random Slytherin girl at Quidditch match" looks to me to be the same as "First Year in Great Hall".

Comment: @FelixDombek - I think you're probably right.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to see the glasses on "First Year in boat behind Harry" (second picture). Is it the boy on the left or half cut on the right?

Comment: @Valorum I'm just gonna take you on faith for that x) Unless I should rewatch that movie after 20 years into adulthood. Hmm...

Comment: @Clockwork - I think you might be right. I can't get a very good view of him on the video and I'm going to try and find a set photo. For now he's coming down off the list.

Answer (score 56):

In the films I've spotted at least one other student wearing glasses in Harry's year. We can see her over Harry's shoulder in the Sorting Hat scene in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*.

[image: Close up on the first year students' faces, a girl with glasses is seen over Harry's shoulder]

We also know of other students who wore glasses, just that they weren't students at the same time as Harry.

#### James Potter

[image: The Marauders in their final years at Hogwarts]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Moaning Myrtle

[image: Close up of Moaning Myrtle]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

We of course also know of various teachers at Hogwarts who wore glasses who may or may not have worn them as children: McGonagall, Dumbledore, Flitwick, Trelawney, etc.

Lastly, in the mobile game *Harry Potter: Hogwarts Mystery*, we know of 3 students, at least, that wore glasses:

- [Liz Tuttle](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Liz_Tuttle)

  [image: Close on Liz's shoulders and head]
  <sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>
- [Rowan Khanna](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Rowan_Khanna)

  [image: Rowan stands smiling in the foreground with the male version off in the background also wearing glasses]
  <sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>
- [Elora Dunn](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Elora_Dunn)

  [image: Close on Elora's sad face in a classroom]
  <sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Meh, film-based answer. The very first part of this could be down to "a random extra needed glasses IRL" more than "they wanted to show another character with glasses". James Potter I think *did* wear glasses in canon though?

Comment: @Randal'Thor TBF the meme is film-based, so answers from the films would be more accurate to the meme/inspiration for the question. That said the only film one here that is not true to the books as well would be the random extra and that's only because there's likely nothing to support that in the books as it's just an extra. I could have done a full list, like the book answer, but I didn't really feel that was needed, just enough to prove the answer.

Comment: Granted. Your answer is valid and I haven't downvoted it, I just feel it's a bit meh and the other one is better and more canonical.

Comment: Aside from the Rowan image, it seems that the choice of frames in Harry Potters world is rather limited.  OT, but thinking about glasses in general: optometry is a science based technology from the muggle world.  So why/how does the magic world even use it? :D

Comment: I'd guess that the girl in the first image behind Harry is maybe the same person as Elora Dunn.  Obviously it's cartoonified, but they've got the same facial structure and approximate hairstyle.

Comment: Rowan Khanna is a boy or girl depending on your player character. So Rowan is one of those two in your image. (This comment in reference to "Rowan Khanna plus an unnamed character I believe.")

Comment: @BrianJ Ah not played the game, shall update to fix that.

Comment: @PeterM The earliest examples in real life of eyeglasses date to the late 13th century AD and Venice already had guild regulations about making them by 1301 AD, whereas wizard society seems to have branched off from muggle society some time around start of the time of the Renaissance, about a century or two later, so it’s not unreasonable to see them used by wizards. There are plenty of other examples of wizards using similarly ‘historic’ sciences throughout the series, it’s the modern stuff that they stay away from.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn OTOH Harry received his glasses before going to Hogwarts, so he probably must have seen a muggle optometrist.  And that optometrist would have used the full slew of modern scientific instruments to examine Harry's eyes and figure out the prescription that Harry needs.  So unless Harry exchanged his glasses for a "magically" produced glasses then Harry is still relying on modern science and technology in order to see.  But all of this pure speculation as I'm sure the stance of optometrists is not defined in canon.

Comment: @PeterM There are other examples of wizards adopting Muggle tech, especially where it's not electronic or doesn't require a "tech person" to maintain - most notably toilets, which got a whole write-up somewhere, probably Pottermore.  For that matter, the Hogwarts Express and clocks are probably the most technologically intricate things that wizards use regularly.

Comment: This is more glasses in 7 movies and one game than I have seen in my entire life - holy cow! +1!